# Is transaction data the same as transaction input?

Tags: web3js, transactions

The [Ethereum RPC API documentation](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sendtransaction) accepts a `data` field when requesting to `sendTransaction`.

> [image]

I notice that when I retrieve a historical transaction from the blockchain, I get back an `input` field and no `data` field, such as when using the [web3 `getTransaction` function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction).

Are the `data` and `input` fields equivalent, or are there any differences?

Comment: I believe so, because there is only one "data" field that can be sent in a transaction, along with the other transaction parameters (gas, address, nonce, etc). This data is often called payload data. It is the code that will be executed by the EVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same thing.

When you're going to send a transaction, the data is the combination of:
`method, parameters` which are defined in the ABI, and they're encoded.

```
data: tokenContract.methods.setPoints(user, point).encodeABI()
```

When you decode the input data then you'll see something like:

```
{
  "method": "addLiquidity",
  "types": [
    "address",
    "address",
    "uint256",
    "uint256",
    "uint256",
    "uint256",
    "address",
    "uint256"
  ],
  "inputs": [
    "f45b409a2b978ec02Bb6084e6Acc42867a78Ee9c",
    "326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB",
    {
      "type": "BigNumber",
      "hex": "0x043c33c1937564800000"
    },
    {
      "type": "BigNumber",
      "hex": "0x038d7ea4c68000"
    },
    {
      "type": "BigNumber",
      "hex": "0x01"
    },
    {
      "type": "BigNumber",
      "hex": "0x01"
    },
    "f39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
    {
      "type": "BigNumber",
      "hex": "0x61fcafda"
    }
  ],
  "names": [
    "tokenA",
    "tokenB",
    "amountADesired",
    "amountBDesired",
    "amountAMin",
    "amountBMin",
    "to",
    "deadline"
  ]
}
```

This is created by the `encodeABI()` function.
There's an [online lab](https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/) to check for the input. You can use it to check the input data. Given we can decode it manually, but it faster to use tool.